# get Route name in View

Tags: php, view, controller, laravel

I trying to design navigation menu,
I have 3 Items like this:

- Dashboard
- Pages

  - List
  - Add
- Articles

  - List
  - Add

Now I want to bold `Pages` when user is in this section,

and if is in `Add` page I want bold both `Pages` and `Add`

my `routes.php` is :

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'), function()
{
    Route::any('/', 'App\Controllers\Admin\PagesController@index');
    Route::resource('articles', 'App\Controllers\Admin\ArticlesController');
    Route::resource('pages', 'App\Controllers\Admin\PagesController');
});
```

I found thid method :

```
$name = \Route::currentRouteName();
var_dump($name);
```

But this method return `string 'admin.pages.index' (length=17)`

Should I use `splite` to get controller or Laravel have a method for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this (to get current action, i.e. `HomeController@index`)

```
Route::currentRouteAction();
```

This will return `action` like `HomeController@index` and you can use something like this in your view

```
<!-- echo the controller name as 'HomeController' -->
{{ dd(substr(Route::currentRouteAction(), 0, (strpos(Route::currentRouteAction(), '@') -1) )) }}

<!-- echo the method name as 'index' -->
{{ dd(substr(Route::currentRouteAction(), (strpos(Route::currentRouteAction(), '@') + 1) )) }}
```

The `Route::currentRouteName()` method returns the name of your route that is used as `'as' => 'routename'` in your route declaration.

Comment: It is not advisable to start applying string manipulations in the view like this. It works but is messy. If you need modify values before presenting them in a view, consider a modifier. As for the parts needed for the navigation menu, `Request::segments()` provides much.

Comment: @nJGL Agreed! Now I wouldn't do this, at least after these years :-)

Answer (score 14):

In Blade:

```
<p style="font-weight:{{ (Route::current()->getName() == 'admin.pages.index' && Request::segment(0) == 'add') ? 'bold' : 'normal' }};">Pages</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

`Request::segments()` will return an array with the current url for example:

```
yoursite/admin/users/create
```

will give:

```
array(2) {
    [0] "admin"
    [1] "users"
    [2] "create"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I use this in `view` ? I mean is in `Blade` templates

Comment: The Request is acessible in Views, but you can also pass it using the `with` method like: View::make('your-view')->with(array('activeController' => Request::segment(2))); or 'activeMenus' => Request::segments()