# get current route name in js file laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a js file from where calling laravel file using ajax call.

```
\Route::currentRouteName()
```

This return null.I want to get routename in ajax call.

How can I get it? I am using laravel 6.18

Comment: Please also include the JS file. Also, is the JS file rendered by Laravel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632714/get-route-name-in-view

Comment: `$route = Route::current();`
`$name = Route::currentRouteName();`
`$action = Route::currentRouteAction();`

Comment: @TalhaF. I want to get name in js file

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the route name, use `Route::current()->getName()` , but do not forget to chain name method to your route in web.php like: `->name('route_name')`.

Get url without query string `url()->current()` and with query string, use: `url()->full()`

Comment: I want routename in js file